# 2001 buick century security system preventing car from starting

Tags: key, buick, security, century

purchased a new key security light stays on then turns off car still does not turn on on line video suggest to bypass security system by soldering a resistor of equal value to the key to the wires sending the signal to the system need help to pin point the wires

Comment: In this case I recommend you bring the car to the dealer to get the keys correctly reprogrammed.